# Car insurance for borrowed car

Tags: automobiles, insurance

My friend lives in the US and he has offered me the use of his car while he is away for a couple of months.

I was already interested in the model of his vehicle so I’m thinking of accepting his offer. The thing is I live in Canada so I’m not sure what kind of insurance I need while I drive his car here.

I learned that I need a letter of permission while crossing to border to prove that I’m borrowing his car and it’s not stolen, however; I couldn’t find any information regarding insurance.

I saw on a forum that his insurance should cover any accidents in Canada but since I’m planning to drive it for a few months, I’m not sure if I need to be registered as the secondary driver in his policy. If so, is an Ontario license sufficient for registration?

Comment: These are questions for your or your friend's insurance providers

Comment: Wait, will you be taking your friends's car across national borders?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because only the friend’s insurance company can provide a reliable answer

Comment: The question about insurance is actually irrelevant. If you are a Canadian resident, you are with a few irrelevant exceptions not allowed to drive US registered cars there.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo That sounds like an answer :-)

Comment: Okay thanks everyone! We’ll contact the insurance provider.